# Word Document Formatting Issue

Tags: ms-word, formatting, wildcard, gift

I am currently trying to manipulate a Word file to get it in a proper format to convert it to a GIFT format. Currently, I have the document in the following form:

This is a question?

a Correct Answer

b Distractor

c Distractor

d Distractor

This is also a question?

a Correct Answer

b Distractor

c Distractor

d Distractor

I am trying to get it into the following form:
[Ideal Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgAmp.png)

Here are the issues.

1. I need to remove the a, b, c, d in from of each of the possible answers.
2. I need to remove the space between each of the choices. The file is already in single space so changing the spacing in paragraph won't work.
3. Add an * to the first response.

I've been trying different wildcards and have had some success getting it to this point, but I'm stuck here. Are there any solutions outside of manually deleting the spaces, letters and adding the asterisk? I need to be able to do this in large batched because there are ~1000 items.

Comment: I figured it out. It involves being careful about your steps and using some excel functions. If anyone else has this issue, I can give them more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It involves being careful about your steps and using some excel functions. If anyone else has this issue, I can give them more detail

Comment: Please give more details..